# Dynamically choose list type to iterate over a common for loop

Tags: java, java-8

I have a for loop which applies a Function for each element of a list. The list could be of type String or Long. Depending on a condition, I need to either iterate the String list or the Long list. Is there a way where I can do it without using if - else?

```
public static <T, S> T weirdFunction(Function<S, T> myFunction, Boolean convertToLong){
      List<String> stringList = fetchFromSomewhere();
      
      if(convertToLong){
        // fetch list of longs from elsewhere
      }
        
      for (<String or Long> id : List<String> or List<Long>) { // choose list type based on some method param
            myFunction.apply(id); // myFunction is of type Function
        }
}
```

Comment: `List<String>` and `List<Long>` are static types, so why would you need `if` statement to choose which to execute, given that the code doing it has either one or the other, and knows which one, since it is... you know... static?

Comment: What is the purpose of the function? I’d recommend to find the lowest common base class which you can use and export the for loop into a template function.

Comment: The function returns another function? Weird!

Comment: @Andreas apologies for the earlier snippet. It was misleading, Made corrections

Comment: So if `convertToLong` is false *(why is it a `Boolean`, not a `boolean`?)*, then how will the `Function<Long, T>` be applicable? The method would need a `Function<String, T>` instead, and you can't do that with a static language like Java. Create two methods `<T> T applyFunctionString(Function<String, T> myFunction)` and `<T> T applyFunctionLong(Function<Long, T> myFunction)`.

Answer (score 1):

Having a function that returns another function, to be applied "recursively"<sup>1</sup>, makes this tricky.

Here is how it can be done:

```java
@FunctionalInterface
interface ChainFunction<T> extends Function<T, ChainFunction<T>> {
    // Nothing to add
}
```

```java
static <T> ChainFunction<T> applyFunctionChain(List<T> list, ChainFunction<T> myFunction) {
    for (T id : list) {
        myFunction = myFunction.apply(id);
    }
    return myFunction;
}
```

The method can be called with `String` and with `Long`, and any other type for that matter.

<sup>*1) "Recursive" is not the right word, but I don't know what it's called.*</sup>

Answer (score 1):

This presents one approach to call a different function per type without using an if statement. It requires one to build a map of different classes the list contains, each with a particular function. The containing class that houses the methods is `SpecialList`  There is a caveat in this.  Since the return value is cast to its actual type it can't be assigned in the loop unless it is returned as an Object.  If the return type is not needed, then the return type could be set to `void` and the `FunctionalInterface` in the map could be a `Consumer`

```
Map<Class<?>, Function<Object, Object>> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(String.class, SpecialList::stringFnc);
map.put(Long.class, SpecialList::longFnc);

List<Object> list = List.of("String1", 123L, "String2", 1234L,
        29292L, "String4");
for (Object ob : list) {
    map.get(ob.getClass()).apply(ob);
}
        
public static String stringFnc(Object str) {
    String v = (String)str;
    //  now do something with v.
    System.out.println("String : " + v);
    return v;
}
    
public static Long longFnc(Object lng) {
    long v = (Long)lng;
    // now do something with v
    System.out.println("Long : " + v);
    return v;
}
```

prints

```
String : String1
Long : 123
String : String2
Long : 1234
Long : 29292
String : String4
```